# Upgrade from 14 to 23 for business starter app from Pro subscription

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am upgrading an app built on the business starter project from the Pro subscription. Has this starter been discontinued? It is no longer available from the starter example page.

Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't that just a menu on the left-hand side? That was replaced with the regular starters and the AppLayouts some time ago?

Comment: It was more than just a menu. There were navigation drawers, multiple tabs, custom styling, support for more than just Spring (not everyone uses Spring). It was in fact one of the main reason's that I moved from the free Vaadin to the Pro subscription because it gave me a lot of the UI framework out the box. There were several updates to it which I incorporated over the years.

Comment: I also justified paying the subscription by using the starter app, and now it does seem to have been dropped.  I'm having some issues with the navigation drawers and find very little information out there.  Would be helpful to hear an official statement from Vaadin.